# Retaining overlayed icon when using image zoom effect

Tags: css

I have added an image zoom effect when the user hovers their mouse over an image in my image gallery. I have a red heart icon overlapped each image (a like button) which is overlapped using CSS grid. When hovering over an image, the zoom effect works but the icon disappears.

I have tried just adding the zoom effect to just the image container but I am unable to use overflow:hiden this way and the images just overlap each other when hovering.

Relevant html:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
  <div class="image-container" *ngFor="let image of galleryList" [ngClass]="generatingClassName(image)">
    <div *ngIf="checkLike(image.imagePath) && isLoggedIn" class="heart-icon-container">
      <ion-icon name="heart" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!checkLike(image.imagePath) && isLoggedIn" class="heart-icon-container">
      <ion-icon name="heart-outline" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <img [src]="image.imagePath" alt="Praying to the Sun" class="image" (click)="onImageSelect(image)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.image {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
    box-shadow: white 1px;
}

.image-container {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-template-columns: 1; 
    grid-template-rows: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px white solid;

}

.image-container img {
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.image-container:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Screenshot of app when not hovering on any images:

[image]

Screenshot of app when hovering on image (see top row, 2 image in from the right):

[image]